# Documentation Tool for TypeScript like JSDoc

Tags: comments, typescript, documentation-generation, jsdoc

Is there any tool for Typescript to auto-generate documentation from annotated comments?

I tried using JSDoc with TypeScript. It works upto some extent but they just are not meant to work together.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: You're right, JSDoc does not currently work with TypeScript files, even if they're compiled to JavaScript. [JSDoc issue #272](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/272) describes some of the compatibility problems. TypeScript support is unlikely to be implemented anytime soon.

Comment: @JeffWilliams That article is from 2012.  Do you know if there have been any recent updates on this?  They [support ECMAScript 6 classes now](http://usejsdoc.org/howto-es2015-classes.html).  But if I write a typescript class, and it compiles down to ECMAScript 5, I lose the "class" keyword. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or alternatively, somebody created this which might work for you http://functorial.com/typescript-docs/

Comment: Dead link as of December 2016.

Answer (score 2):

In my knowledge -- not yet!

However, there is jsdoc themselves are planning on providing support for typescript. However, not sure when!